# .Net 6 How detect action filter is on Controller or Action method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, action-filter

I have an action filter like this:

```
 public class TestAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
  {
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
      {
        var onController= ?//here I want to detect whether attribute is on controller or action
      }

    public int Order { get; }
  }
```

And I put attribute on controller like this (I know for sake of this purpose you need to use IFilterFactory or ServiceFilter but I removed them for simplicity):

```
[Test]
public class FileController : BaseApiController
```

Or for Action methods:

```
[Test]
public async Task<ActionResult<FileResponse>> UploadAsync()
```

So my question is how to detect this attribute is execute for controller scope or action scope in .net 6?

Comment: [IAsyncActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters/_static/filter-pipeline-2.png?view=aspnetcore-6.0) simply won't run if an action isn't tied to the request. Maybe you're looking for [Authorization filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization-filters) or [Resource filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#resource-filters)?

Comment: So even I use Authorization filter then I can use it on controller or action so the question is how can I detect it's executing on controller or action?

Comment: Did you tried this way?   `string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It gives me controller name, but I want to know when attribute execute it's for a controller (filter on controller) or  not?

Comment: It will execute as it's sequence as you can [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs#the-base-actionfilterattribute-class). I am still bit confused what you are looking for, how the attribute execute in sequence or want to get the atrribute details.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks for the link, you know I'm looking for a solution like ``Authorize`` action filter in Identity, if you put Authorize on a controller it will authorize all action methods no matter which action calls, this is exactly what I want, if my attribute put on controller then detect it and do different job but if it put on action do another thing.

Comment: Well I got your point, you can use reflection to achieve this. [Here is the official document how you can implement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection). something like `var attribVariable = (filterContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks, I will test it asap and let you know it works or not

Comment: No problem take your time and keep us posted.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you;

```
 public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var currentFilter = context.ActionDescriptor
            .FilterDescriptors
            .FirstOrDefault(filterDescriptor => ReferenceEquals(filterDescriptor.Filter, this));


        if (currentFilter == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (currentFilter.Scope == FilterScope.Action)
        {
            //..
        }

        if (currentFilter.Scope == FilterScope.Controller)
        {
            //...
        }

        await next();
    }
```